# Re-order collection with simple_form DSL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I am using the following DSL in simple_form:

```
<%= m.association :accessories, label_method: :full_name, value_method: :id, include_blank: false %>
```

I would like to re-order the dropdown list to be sorted alphabetically by `:full_name`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [simple_form readme](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#associations), there's no option to do that.  In order to achieve what you want to do, you can pass a `collection` option.

```
<%= m.association :accessories, collection: Accessory.order(:name), label_method: :full_name, value_method: :id, include_blank: false %>
```

Comment: Hi I want to order by full name, not name. Is this possible

Comment: it is. if `full_name` is a column, just change `:name` to `:full_name`.  If it is a method, you'd have to craft some sql to mimic how `full_name` is implemented, most probably using `CONCAT` for mysql and `||` for postgresql